# Matlab code for regular graphs on given number of vertices

Tags: matlab, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

A regular graph is a graph whose each vertex has same degree (number of edges incident to a vertex). Its adjacency matrix follow the criteria that each row sum and column sum is same and is equal to the regularity of the graph.  There could be many such graphs. For example see http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/reggraphs.html#CRG. I need a generating code to produce the adjacency matrix of all such regular graphs on a given number of vertices. So could anyone suggest me the Matlab code or the algorithm to generate the adjacency matrices of all the different regular graphs on a fixed number of vertices. There is code (see for example: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29786-random-regular-generator) for generating random regular graphs but I have not yet found the code for generating all the regular graphs on a given number of vertices.

Comment: I've reopened the question because I tagged it as the wrong duplicate, but you are asking us to find you a resource, and that is still off-topic.  This will eventually close again.

Comment: Check this newer [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355405/how-to-generate-all-3-regular-graphs-given-number-of-vertices-in-python/41379131#41379131).