# how to generate all 3 regular graphs given number of vertices in python

Tags: python, graph-theory

I want to generate all 3-regular graphs with given number of vertices to check if some property applies to all of them or not. checking the property is easy but first I have to generate the graphs efficiently.

Can somebody please help me Generate these graphs (as adjacency matrix) or give me a file containing such graphs. Number of vertices are less than 24.

Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn

Comment: Maybe I explain my problem poorly. I don't want to visualize anything. my question is in graph theory. I want to generate adjacency matrix for all 3 regular graphs possible for given number of vertices.

Comment: http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/reggraphs.html

Comment: I saw this page but i could not figure out how to read scd files. the format is not clear

Comment: @aliasgharGorzin What about -a option? http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/manual/genreg.html

Comment: -a option is only for graphs with 12 vertex or less. 18 is good enough for me (in this site list for 3 regular graphs with 18 vertex or less is avalible) but 12 is small

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to read scd file into python as binary and convert data in same way it is done in readscd.c file. Here is an example:

```
import numpy

def convert(filename, n, k=3):
    num_edges = n*k/2
    f = open(filename, "r")
    values = numpy.fromfile(f, dtype=numpy.uint8)
    read_values = 0
    code = []
    while read_values < len(values):
        # dekomp(file,code)
        samebits = values.item(read_values)
        read_values += 1
        readbits = num_edges - samebits
        code = code[:samebits] + list(values[read_values:read_values+readbits])
        read_values += readbits
        # codetonlist(code,l)
        graph = numpy.zeros((n, n), dtype=numpy.uint8)
        v = 0
        count = [0] * n
        for w in code:
            w -= 1  # We are indexing from 0
            while(count[v] == k):
                v += 1
            # edge (v, w)
            graph.itemset((v, w), 1)
            graph.itemset((w, v), 1)
            count[v] += 1
            count[w] += 1
        yield graph

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    nk = filename.split('.')[0].split('_')
    for g in convert(filename, int(nk[0]), int(nk[1])):
        print g
```

File 18_3_3.scd is processed in few seconds. Printing took few minutes.

Comment: @aliasgharGorzin You are welcome. Now I know few more things about graph generation :-)

Comment: this one helped a lot. i checked my parameter for cubic graphs with 18 vertex or less.

Comment: can you please give me a source to read about graph generation? I think i need to generate cubic graphs with 20 vertices.

Comment: @aliasgharGorzin To generate graphs use genreg application that can be downloaded from upper page. I downloaded sources, compiled it, and it works. Paper that describes how generation is done can be found on Dr. Markus's page. Link is http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/pdf/pub/FastGenRegGraphJGT.pdf

Comment: @aliasgharGorzin On my laptop 'genreg 20 3 -s' runs few seconds, and 'genreg 22 3 -s' runs ~40 seconds.

Comment: I can not download the file. the link "ftp://ftp.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/meringer/GENREG/genreg.tar" does not work. did you download it from somewhere else?

Comment: @aliasgharGorzin Yes, link is broken. I googled for genreg.tar and found it in few archives.

Comment: first i want to thank you for being so patient with me. I have another question and I promise it is going to be my last one. I downloaded the genreg.tar file. but I don't know how to run it. I tried gcc  but I couldn't do it. what should I do to run it?

Comment: @aliasgharGorzin Just 'make'. There is makefile in source which describes whole building process.